# Mage::getModel('customer/address') broke the system

Tags: magento-1.9.4.1

I was developing a custom shipping module using

> Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getCollection()->setCustomerFilter($sellerIDVar)

Using this code broke the page or module. Could you please anybody find the problem ?

I'm using Magento 1.9.4.1

EDIT

---

I wanted the default billing or default shipping address set of the customer. So when i get the collection with entity_type_id filtered, theres no address !!!

And when i use the Load method, i get all addresses of the customer. So im in trouble with both methods.

helps solicited dears.

Comment: is there any error in log Or page ?

Comment: @Pawan, no i dont have any log as my system has some error with logging.

Comment: You can enable `error reporting` from index.php to see exact error.

Comment: dont use setCustomerFilter, just use ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id',$customer_id)

Comment: @leo you are right, I suggest you add this in answer instead of comments

Comment: what value `$sellerIDVar` is containing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code instead of your code, if you want to use same line of statement then @leo comment is right. you should use `addFieldToFilter('parent_id',$sellerIDVar)`. I prefer you follow below code in order to fetch customer address info.

The address information is stored within the Mage_Customer_Model_Customer so you should be able to create an instance of it with the customer id.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($sellerIDVar);
```

Then depending on the type of address that you are looking for you should be able to call one of the following functions.

> Primary Billing Address:

```
$customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress();
```

> Primary Shipping Address:

```
$customer->getPrimaryShippingAddress();
```

> General Address Selection:

```
$customer->getAddressItemById();
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thank you, but this returns all address of the customer.

Comment: this didnt help atall. sorry.

Comment: You declare the `$sellerIDVar` variable. So I assume `$sellerIDVar` containing customer Id. You pass the correct  customer Id  to `$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($sellerIDVar);` it will return specific customer